# force computer not to restart after install product with batch script

Tags: batch-file, restart

I am working on product testing automation. After product installation, I need computer still on instead of restart automatically. Anyone can help me how to force computer not to restart using Batch script.
Thank so much

Comment: what OS do you use? linux? windows?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that might work. Run it in the background while installing.

```
:start
shutdown /a 2>NUL
timeout 1
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

just run

```
shutdown /a
```

after the installation.